# Permissions, Python Script

Tags: python

I am learning to write Python Scripts for work and I have run into some problems. The script is supposed to read a file, and print the permissions to an email. My problem is I am getting an error when it tries to call the permission() method, and I don't know how to fix it.

**Python Code**

```
import smtplib
import os
import stat

result = ""
def permission(file):
        s = os.stat(file)
        mode = s.st_mode

        if(stat.S_IRUSR & mode):
            ownerRead = 1
            result += ownerRead
        else:
            ownerRead = 0
            result += ownerRead
        if(stat.S_IWUSR & mode):
            ownerWrite = 1
            result += ownerWrite
        else:
            ownerWrite = 0
            result += ownerWrite
        if(stat.S_IXUSR & mode):
            ownerExecute = 1
            result += ownerExecute
        else:
            ownerExecute = 0
            result += ownerExecute
        if(stat.S_IRGRP & mode):
            groupRead = 1
            result += groupRead
        else:
            groupRead = 0
            result += groupRead
        if(stat.S_IWGRP & mode):
            groupWrite = 1
            result += groupWrite
        else:
            groupWrite = 0
            result += groupWrite
        if(stat.S_IXGRP & mode):
            groupExecute = 1
            result += groupExecute
        else:
            groupExecute = 0
            result += groupExecute
        if(stat.S_IROTH & mode):
            otherRead = 1
            result += otherRead
        else:
            otherRead = 0
            result += otherRead
        if(stat.S_IWOTH & mode):
            otherWrite = 1
            result += otherWrite
        else:
            otherWrite = 0
            result += otherWrite
        if(stat.S_IXOTH & mode):
            otherExecute = 1
            result += otherExecute
        else:
            otherExecute = 0
            result += otherExecute
        return result
to = 'email@yahoo.com'
gmail_user = 'email@gmail.com'
gmail_pwd = 'pwd'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:permissions \n'
print header
values = permission(file)
print values
msg = header + values
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()
```

**Error Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lastpart.py", line 83, in <module>
    values = permission(file)
  File "lastpart.py", line 15, in permission
    s = os.stat(file)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found
```

Comment: Try renaming the parameter of your function? `file` is a type name already, and apparently, python is getting confused by having the parameter called `file` as well.

Comment: @Ulrich: No, Python can keep them straight. But the asker can't.

Answer (score 3):

You fix it by passing the actual filename to the function, not the `file` built-in type.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
```

Name your variable something other than `file`, and actually pass a filename to it. You never actually define the thing you're passing to your call of the function, and thus the only reason it's not crashing with an undefined variable error is because Python happens to already define something with that name, built-in.